# How to show answer from yes/no item

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a uniform order form where at the summary total i want to show if embroidery was selected for that particular item. Currently Embroidery is a yes/no radio button and I just want it to show up in the payment summary as Embroidery: Yes or No depending on what was selected in the form. How do I go about showing the "Yes" or "No" answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Price field in Cognito Forms to have complete control over the appearance of line items that appear in the payment summary.  You can specify the following for each Price field:

1. Amount: The amount of the line item, which can be negative and includes support for constant values or calculations.  You can also hide Price fields and only have the amount appear in the payment summary.
2. Name: The name of the line item, like "Embroidery" in your case.  This can also be a calculation.
3. Description: The description or detail of the line item, like "Yes" or "No" in your case.  You could use a calculation like:
   =if Embroidery then "Yes" else "No"